# alignment of images in columns with containers

Tags: html, css

I'm going to re-ask this question in a more simple way:
I am using the following [code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_images_side_by_side) from W3school, but I need to change the images to 50% which creates a huge gap between the columns. Is there a way to align the left column to the right so that the images are close together?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Images Side by Side</h2>
<p>How to create side-by-side images with the CSS float property:</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to use `text-align: left` or vice-versa. To make this easier you could always use bootstrap grid layout

Comment: could you please provide an example image/ url

Comment: You could try a `<table>`.

Comment: David, would I use a table instead of columns/rows?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to learn how to ask good questions!

Answer (score 1):

So I think I "fixed" your issue with flexbox but I would suggest reordering your code structure. You can see the fix below. Also, I wrote an article on CSS references that you should check out. There are several links that I use almost daily when designing UI. Heres the link...

https://medium.com/@hunter.campbell843/css-references-for-new-developers-and-old-6e3dbead437f

```html
.column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;                   //These are the only
  justify-content: center;         //things i added
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Hunter! This almost worked - it looks better but there is still a bunch of white space in the centre. Ideally I'd love the images to be tiled together. Maybe I should try a table instead of columns?

Comment: Try looking into reordering your containers and using flex-wrap. I'm not big on tables myself but if you like using them then I'm sure it could be manipulated in the way you want it to be. If you want to go the flexbox way check out this link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/